# Compare mobile and desktop usage over time in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, usage-data, desktop

Is there any custom dashboard to compare mobile vs desktop traffic over a year time period? I want to know how much usage has moved to mobile devices from desktop month by month.

Answer (score 3):

Like many "compare over time" questions, this is hidden in Google Analytics with "motion charts".

[image]

1. Navigate to "Audience" -> "Mobile" -> "Overview"
2. Set the time frame to 1 year
3. Select motion charts using the icon with three dots on the top right of the graph
4. Select the line chart tab that appear at the top of the chart
5. Change the sideways menu from "% New Sessions" to "Sessions"
6. (Optional) Select "Week" view to smooth out the graph.

This highlights several weaknesses of the usability of Google Analytics:

- Why is this type of report buried so deep in Google Analytics that nobody finds it?
- Why is a line chart hidden under "motion charts"?
- Why is the default metric on motion charts "% New Sessions"?
- Why is choosing a time frame of an even number of weeks so difficult?  (I wrote [a utility to make it easier for me to select a year of weeks in Google Analytics](http://ostermiller.org/calc/ga.html))

Comment: Is this still accurate in 2018? I can't seem to find the sideways menu

Comment: @Ryan it is still there.  You have to click on the bubble icon first.  The only wrinkle is that the motion charts are Adobe Flash.   They don't work for me at all in Chrome anymore.   In Firefox I have to click on "run flash" after I click on the bubbles.

Comment: Agreed on the poor UI design burying this crucial type of report. Also, they're still using Flash in 2019!